# Removing index & controller from URL Codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am creating a small website and would like to remove the index.php and the controller welcome from the URL string. My mod_rewrite looks like;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 // remove index.php / welcome

</IfModule>
```

My application will look like;

```
index($pagename){

//pull from database where page name is $pagename
// get head, insert $pagename, insert footer etc


}
```

Comment: Have you tried the CodeIgniter documentation to begin with? https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 1):

For removing index.php update your .htaccess file with the following code :

```
 RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Hope it works in removing index.php

Comment: please also add instructions to change $config['index_page'] = 'index.php' to empty string in config.php.

Comment: just remove index.php like

$config['index_page'] = '   ';

Comment: i was asking you to update your answer, so that is covers all the cases. :)